# RecyclerView with ExoPlayer/VideoView bad Performance

Tags: android, android-videoview, exoplayer

I want to play Videos in my RecyclerView Items, kind of like Instagram. There is only one Item expanded at a time so the Videos don't have to be played at the same time.

Im currently using the ExoPlayer. I have a PlayerView inside my item for the RecyclerView.

The problem is, with the Player I have bad performance which is very bad when scrolling and expanding. The Performany is already bad with just having the Player in the item without loading and playing a Video but it gets even worse with loading it.

I have tried VideoView too but it doesn't seem to make a big difference.

To achieve a better performance I already do:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
adapter.hasStableIds();
```

This helps a little bit but its doesn't solve the performance problem.

Any Idea what the problem can be? I appreciate and thoughts.

EDIT:

this is the method I setup the ExoPlayer:

```
public void showTutuorItems(Context context, Boolean show, String resource) {
        if (show) {
            seperator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lytTutor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exoPlayer);
            playerView.setUseController(false);

            playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exoPlayer);
            playerView.setUseController(false);

            SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                    new DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
                    new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());

            playerView.setPlayer(player);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            player.seekTo(0, 0);
            player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
            player.setVolume(0);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(resource);
            MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
            player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);

            player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
                //...
            }


        } else {
            seperator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lytTutor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {

        return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab")).
                createMediaSource(uri);
    }
```

and this is in my OnCreateViewHolder to call this method:

```
if (workout.getCurrentExercsise().getTutor() != null) {
        holder.showTutuorItems(activity, true, workout.getCurrentExercsise().getTutor().getItems().get(0).getResource());
    } else {
        holder.showTutuorItems(activity, false, null);
    }
```

In my OnBindViewHolder is some UI stuff and handling the expand/collapse function. This shouldn't cause the problem because without the ExoPlayer it works just fine.

Comment: please provide the code of your adapter too, specially the bindView method

Comment: thanks for the help but thats easier said then done. There is quite a lot of stuff there but that should´t be part of the problem because without the ExoPlayer this code works fine

Comment: Take a look at github.com/eneim/toro and give it a try?

Comment: @Jonas I'm facing the same issue. How did you resolve this?

Comment: Sup man, years laters I'm in the same need, did you achive what you were looking for?